# Get past data on the 6th month from today

Tags: mysql

How do I get the data exactly on the 6th month ago from today?

Eg. now is May 2019, and I want the data exactly 6 months ago, which is Dec 2018.

So I tried writing this code:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE MONTH(UpdatedDate) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH);
```

Problem: This is showing me the result of all the years, which has that particular month. (eg; Dec 2014, Dec 2015, Dec 2016 and so on).

So from trying to solve it, I was thinking it is because I need to make sure to set the year. However, in my example the year cant be set to current year as the result in May 2019 for 6 months ago would be Dec 2018.

So I would like to ask how do I write it in a way so that I can get the data exactly 6 months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query.

```
SELECT * from table WHERE MONTH(UpdatedDate) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND YEAR(UpdatedDate) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH);
```

Problem with your query is your searching data based on month only hence getting all year data.

Try to fetch data on year and month as demonstrated in above query.

Comment: Oh my, this is brilliant! It works really well. It fetches the data exactly from that specified month. 5 mins to accept as correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this solution cannot use an index, but a variant on the theme could

Answer (score 1):

You could also:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(UpdatedDate,'%Y-%m')=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 5 MONTH,'%Y-%m');
```